# Chrome 83: Change colors of new form styling

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, checkbox

With the [new Chrome update](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html) Chrome is displaying improved default form styling.
According to the post I would say it should be possible to change this form theme to match the color set of a website.

> We were going for beautiful, webby, and neutral. We hope that every design system would see a bit of themselves in the new designs and easily imagine how they might be adapted for their own branding.

I have spend the last few hours searching and trying to get rid of the default blue color that has a very bad contrast with rest of my website. Aside from using '-webkit-appearance: none;' and restyling things like checkboxes myself I'm not sure if it's possible.

Does anyone experience this issue as well or have a solution or documentation I'm missing?

Comment: Wesley, I added an answer. Not ideal, a bit of a tweak, but at least it is simple.

Answer (score 11):

My preferred solution just uses css. It targets Safari as well as Chrome, but it's already grayscale anyway, so that's OK.

`input[type='checkbox']:checked {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}
input[type='radio']:checked {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}`

Answer (score 5):

> **This is Chrome 83 upwards specific** - other browsers do other things (grayscale mostly).

---

This construct seems to work for now - just as long as there is a background color set for `"body"`:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

***Examples***:

[image: Check boxes]

Though I am not sure this will continue to work, it might be good enough as a temporary workaround to alleviate "designer suffering". Disrupted color schemes is a crisis :-).

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }  
    input[type=checkbox] {
          mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
 <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Test</label>
</body>

</html>
```

---

***Links***:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_mix-blend-mode.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 4):

Pure CSS solution which allows any color while trying to stay close to the new design. Just replace the --primary-color variable.  Works in Chromium browsers (Chrome, new Edge) and Firefox.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #f44336;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #767676;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover::before {
  border: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:hover::before {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled:hover::before {
  filter: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1.5px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-1.5px) rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled::before {
  border: 1px solid #c9ced1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f0f4f8;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled::before {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"></input>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" checked="checked"></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using hue-rotate() filter, one can change the background color of checked checkboxes. For example, this css makes it green:

Input[type=checkbox]:checked{filter:hue-rotate(290deg);}

Now, by adding grayscale, one can make the green color darker:

Input[type=checkbox]:checked{filter:hue-rotate(290deg) grayscale(50%);}

The brightness() filter can also help to adjust the color.

Using invert(), you can get a black checkbox, then add grayscale and brightness to get white background (which looks like a regular checkbox, only, without a border):

Input[type=checkbox]:checked{filter:invert() grayscale(100%) brightness(180%);}

Answer (score 1):

It's so ugly one cannot just update the style of checkboxes :( So you need to really hide native checkbox and insert your custom element using `:before`

Here is the snippet using Font Awesome (free icon for checkmark `\f00c`)

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  /* Show the border to simulate the square */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Hide the native checkbox */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  /* Show some fake element to keep the space for empty "square" */
  content: "\f0c8";
  color: transparent;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  /* Show actual checkmark */
  content: "\f00c";
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/59ba4e0c1b.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="">I'm checked
<br>
<input type="checkbox">I'm unchecked
```

And here is the one with pure Unicode (which still requires some polishing to avoid jumping)

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* Show the border to simulate the square */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Hide the native checkbox */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  /* Show some fake element to keep the space for empty "square" */
  content: "w";
  color: transparent;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  /* Show actual checkmark */
  content: "✓";
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="">I'm checked
<br>
<input type="checkbox">I'm unchecked
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to bring back the grey/black checkboxes, targeting only desktop versions of Chrome >= 83.

```
if (window.chrome) {
    var ua = navigator.appVersion;
    if (ua.indexOf('Mobile') === -1) {
        var flag = ua.indexOf('Chrome/');
        if (flag !== -1) {
            var version = parseInt(ua.substr(flag + 7, 2));
            if (version >= 83) {
                var chromeStyle       = document.createElement('style');
                chromeStyle.type      = 'text/css';
                chromeStyle.innerText = 'input[type="checkbox"] {-webkit-filter: brightness(0.9);} input[type="checkbox"]:checked {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) brightness(1.3);}';
                document.head.appendChild(chromeStyle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This change in widget appearance from Chrome 81 to Chrome 83 really badly affected my Gui, in p5.js. I found a way to revert to Chrome 81 style, I don't know how long it will remain available. Put this in your Chrome address bar ..

chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh

It brings up a bunch of internal options .. set the Web Platform Controls updated UI ie. the one you land on, to Disabled. Have to then restart the browser. This gets rid of all the "improvements", including the awful bright blue slider mentioned above.

Thanks to a Reddit poster for the info, which I've lost the URL of.
(My environment: Mac, Mojave 10.14.6, Chrome 83.0.4103.106). (Also now 83.0.4103.116, latest at 25 June 2020).

Ciao e Buona Fortuna.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed! The CSS 'hacks' work only for one page at the time, this does for all of them. And this is the Reddit page you mentioned: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/gnk4jj/chrome_83_blue_checkboxes_default_styling/

Comment: Glad it helped! Unfortunately I've found the "form-controls-refresh" option got disabled at about Chrome 86, and I'm back to the awful blue sliders etc. If you've got this to work on an up-to-date Chrome I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

In **Chrome 91**, maybe you can try the `accent-color` CSS keyword, which allows web developers to specify the accent color for UI controls (e.g. checkbox, radio button) generated by the element.

The accent-color CSS property is currently experimental. Please enable `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` to test it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
      </head>
      <style>
        input[type="checkbox"] {
          accent-color: red;
        }
      </style>
      <body>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was going to need to use `-webkit-appearance: none;`, but turns out it is not necessary. Also, using JavaScript and/or `filter` is unnecessary.

Here is where I landed: https://codepen.io/colorful-tones/pen/NWxZpBb

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Then just style it the way you want.

As for the checked state you can use :before pseudo element with font icon like Fontawesome or with an image like so:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: '';
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(check.png) no-repeat center 3px transparent #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` just hides it for me.
Would be nice to have an example of not random "style way you want" but "here is the style close to the previous versions" (without having need to have some crazy images or dependencies)