# Different / New input field style in new chrome update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My portal's primary color is `#57889c` But the latest chrome update(version: 83) brought some changes in basic style property of input fields like the following images.

**Description:** *new checkbox after checked, new input field after focused*

[image: New checkbox]
[image]

can anyone provide me a css solution? I have used `-webkit-appearance: none;` but it brings no good and i went through the following given [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057910/chrome-83-change-colors-of-new-form-styling). It doesn't work for me.

Comment: You really need to elaborate what exactly you mean by "it doesn't work" as there are three solutions, one of them is nuclear so it should work for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution which allows any color while trying to stay close to the new design. Works in Chromium browsers (Chrome, new Edge) and Firefox.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #57889c;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #767676;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover::before {
  border: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:hover::before {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled:hover::before {
  filter: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1.5px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-1.5px) rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled::before {
  border: 1px solid #c9ced1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f0f4f8;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:disabled::before {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"></input>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true"></input>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" checked="checked"></input>
```